# Excel VBA - Selenium not recognising element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I'm trying to write a script that will navigate this web page

https://www.theclearinghouse.org/uid-lookup

As you can see in the image the element ID is SubmitUid

[image]

But when I use
d.FindElementById("SubmitUid").Click

d being my selenium chrome driver which has already started up and loaded the webpage.(Screenshot is from the browser which selenium launched)

I get a NoSuchElementError

Comment: Your screenshot shows the element you are trying to click is inside a frame. Switch to the frame first and try clicking the element.

Comment: Use this url instead `https://www.theclearinghouse.org/uidhelper.html?height=1002&cacheb=0.86007592133721`

Answer (score 1):

Your target element is located inside an iframe named `uidlookup`.
First you need to use the `switchTo` function and then call for `FindElementById`.

So you code would look something like (this code is in Java, but there are similar functions in VBA):

```
driver.switch_to.frame("uidlookup");

// do selections/clicks

driver.switch_to.default_content(); // move back to iframe
```

Comment: thanks for that, Sorry about the slow reply